# Javascript multiple Inheritance clarification

Tags: javascript, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, prototypal-inheritance, javascript-inheritance

I am new to OOP in Javascript. I am learning Inheritance. Below is my code. I am not using any prototype and create function here but still managed to inherit. I know this is not the right way of doing. But for achieving my goal, how should I rewrite the code in order to utilize the actual inheritance.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Ajax</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            // Validation Class
            var Validation = function() {
                this.isEmpty = function(val) {
                    if (val == "")
                        return true;
                }
            }
            // Ajax Class
            var Ajax = function() {
                this.url = "";
                this.data = "";
                this.send = function(val) {

                    alert("Data send to " + this.url + " succeessfully");
                }
            }
            // Form Class
            var LoginForm = function(action, username, password) {
                Validation.call(this);
                Ajax.call(this);
                this.action = action;
                this.username = username;
                this.password = password;
            }
            var loginObj = new LoginForm("domain/server", "john", '123456');
            loginObj.url = loginObj.action;
            loginObj.isEmpty(loginObj.username);
            loginObj.isEmpty(loginObj.password);
            loginObj.data = {username: loginObj.username, password: loginObj.password};
            loginObj.send();

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** But when I tried like this it is throwing error.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Ajax</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            // Validation Class
            var Validation = function() {
                this.isEmpty = function(val) {
                    if (val == "")
                        return true;
                }
            }
            // Ajax Class
            var Ajax = function() {
                this.url = "";
                this.data = "";
                this.send = function(val) {

                    alert("Data of "+this.data.username+" send to " + this.url + " succeessfully");
                }
            }
            // Inheritance
            Ajax.prototype = Object.create(Validation);  
            
            var LoginForm = "";
            LoginForm.prototype = Object.create(Ajax);
            // Form Class
            LoginForm = function(action, username, password) {    
                this.action = action;
                this.username = username;
                this.password = password;
            }
            var loginObj = new LoginForm("domain/server", "john", '123456');
            loginObj.url = loginObj.action;
            loginObj.isEmpty(loginObj.username);
            loginObj.isEmpty(loginObj.password);
            loginObj.data = {username: loginObj.username, password: loginObj.password};
            loginObj.send();
            
            
            var loginObj2 = new LoginForm("domain/server", "JAMES", '123456');
            loginObj2.url = loginObj2.action;
            loginObj2.isEmpty(loginObj2.username);
            loginObj2.isEmpty(loginObj2.password);
            loginObj2.data = {username: loginObj2.username, password: loginObj2.password};
            loginObj2.send();

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you think you've "inherited". If you mean you can refer properties defined in other functions, that's just becuse you're binding `this` value to the instance of `LoginForm` when calling `Validation` or `Ajax`. No inheritance here.

Comment: What you just did is similar to calling a `super()` constructor in an object oriented language. That's about as close as it gets, because JavaScript doesn't have OOP constructs. (Even `class` and `extend` from ES6 are just syntactic sugar)

Comment: @4castle ES6 does, at least to some extent.